# How do I get IPX on a Windows 10 machine for playing old games such as Diablo 1?

Tags: windows-10, diablo, command-and-conquer-red-alert-2

I have multiple old games that are not available on Steam or GOG such as Diablo 1 and Red Alert 2 that I would like to be able to play multiplayer on my windows 10 machine on my network (i.e. prefer not to mess with Battle Net on Diablo, assuming that even still works). I have added the IPX protocols on older machines via my network properties and just adding IPX. However on my Windows 10 machines the only Network Protocol listed when I go to install is Reliable Multicast Protocol.

Is there still a way to get the IPX protocols added or another workaround for old IPX reliant games?

Comment: Diablo 1 is now available on GOG, in case you did not know.

Comment: Yea diablo you can get on GOG, it's fairly updated with more modern changes, great stuff

Answer (score 1):

For old games, [IPX Wrapper](http://www.solemnwarning.net/ipxwrapper/) is a very good choice.

In the case of Red Alert 2, it is not necessary as it also supports TCP, you just have to get [this .dll](http://overmind.ro/DLLs/wsock32.dll) and copy it to your game dir.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there still a way to get the IPX protocols added or another workaround for old IPX reliant games?

In the specific case of Diablo, [there is a web-based port of the game available which supports online play](https://d07riv.github.io/diabloweb/).